# jQuerytools RangeInput update on scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

Hi I'm using latest version of jquerytools rangeinput to drag a slider and update a donation amount, however my version does not update the range input (amount) on drag only when you complete the drag, here is the link http://bit.ly/12UP4C4 and here is my code. Thanks for the assistance.

```
jQuery(":range").rangeinput({ 
    progress: true,

    change: function(e, i) {
    jQuery('#input_4_4').val(jQuery('.range').val());
    jQuery('.handle').text(jQuery('.range').val());
}});
```

Edit: I have tried using the OnSlide function below as suggested but it does not seem to work with jQuery 1.8, any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the onSlide event instead of change. So something like:

```
jQuery(":range").rangeinput({ 
    progress: true,

    onSlide : function(e, i) {
    jQuery('#input_4_4').val(jQuery('.range').val());
    jQuery('.handle').text(jQuery('.range').val());
}});
```

The change event doesn't happen until after you finished sliding.
Taken from the documentation.
http://jquerytools.org/documentation/rangeinput/index.html